# Javascript delete isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql-delete

My delete function isn't working.

This is my table with the delete button.

```
// retrieve table contents
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

extract($row);

//creating new table row per record
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='text-align-center'><input type='checkbox' name='item[]' class='checkboxes' value='{$employeeid}' /></td>";
    echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$title}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$phone}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$supplier_name}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$created}</td>";
    echo "<td>";

        // update record
        echo "<a href='update_product.php?employeeid={$employeeid}' class='btn btn-info margin-right-1em'>";
            echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Rediger";
        echo "</a>";

        // delete record
        echo "<a delete-employeeid='{$employeeid}' delete-file='delete_product.php' class='btn btn-danger delete-object'>";
            echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Slet";
        echo "</a>";

    echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
//end table<br>
echo "</table>";
```

This is my delete function

```
// delete single record

$(document).on('click', '.delete-object', function(){


// php file used for deletion
var delete_file = $(this).attr('delete-file');

var id = $(this).attr('delete-id');
var q = confirm("Are you sure?");

if (q == true){

    $.post(delete_file, {
        object_id: id
    }, function(data){
        location.reload();
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Unable to delete.');
    });

}
return false;
});
```

I got the code from a tutorial that I modified a lot. 
Everything else is working, except the delete function.

PHP CODE

```
<?php
// check if value was posted
if($_POST){

    // include database and object file
    include_once 'config/database.php';

    // delete query
    $query = "DELETE FROM employeestest WHERE employeeid = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['object_employeeid']);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        // redirect to read records page and 
        // tell the user record was deleted
        echo "Medarbejderen er slettet.";
    }else{
        echo "Medarbejderen kunne ikke slettes.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your delete_product.php??

Comment: `delete-id` is missing from your html. Not sure if it's a copy+paste error though. The php code would help, and the folder structure.

Comment: Many missing parts to really get what's going on here...  need the whole code man...

Comment: Added the php code. I'm kinda confused about the $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['object_employeeid']); line.
Can't figure out what it refers to or where it is used.

Comment: delete-id is not prasent in your JS, Change  $(this).attr('delete-Id'); to $(this).attr('delete-employeeid');

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just made grammar mistake

```
'delete-id' => 'delete-employeeid'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`var id = $(this).attr('delete-Id');`

to

`var id = $(this).attr('delete-employeeid');`

And, Change `$.post` to `$.ajax` as i've given

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-object', function(){
        var delete_file = $(this).attr('delete-file');
        var id = $(this).attr('delete-employeeid');
        var q = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (q == true)
        {
            $.ajax({url:delete-file,cache:false,success:function(result){
                alert('Successfully Deleted');
            }});
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```